# How to understand the meaning of .() in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am confused by .() in data.table. it is hard to search .() in google. So could anyone explain in detail what is .() used for in R data.table please? Thank you!

I would like to show some code for better clarification:

```
df = data.table(col1 = c(1:20), col2 = seq(1, 100, by = 5), col3 = c(replicate(10, "A"), replicate(10, "B")))

df %>% group_by(col3) %>% summarise(mean = mean(col2)) %>% View() `This is what I want in data.table`

df %>% .[, .(mean = mean(col2)), by = col3] %>% View()`# this code is what I want, but it can only run with .(), as I have only one column(col2) in j, my question is why we need .() here?`

df %>% .[, mean := mean(col2), by = col3] %>% View() `this is not what I want as it creates duplicated rows`
```

Comment: it is similar to wrapping with `list(`

Comment: It's short hand. Maybe try the [data.table FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html) and other intro texts slides?  There are lots, and many are very good.  [These](https://raw.githack.com/uo-ec510-2020-spring/lectures/master/05-datatable/05-datatable.html#1) are from yesterday (!!).

Comment: @akrun, thanks for answering , I added some code for clarification, could you take a look please?